# How to fetch consecutive pairs of records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, analytics, grouping

Can somebody give me a clue about a tricky SQL problem. I searched similar problems, the closest approach seemed this, but it is not the solution to my problem:
[Oracle - grouping between pairs of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374084/oracle-grouping-between-pairs-of-records)

I know this can be achieved by a PL/SQL procedure, but in this case (Oracle) SQL is necessary.
I am looking for an Oracle SQL SELECT to isolate special records with IDs = 4 and 5 of a plain table. The table consists of just 2 columns: ID and DATE
It contains data like this:

```
ID  DATE          REMARK (this row is not part of table!)
---------------   ------------------------------------------
2   01-JAN-2013     
4   02-JAN-2013   A  
7   03-JAN-2013  
5   05-JAN-2013   A  
6   07-JAN-2013  
4   08-JAN-2013   B  
1   11-JAN-2013  
5   12-JAN-2013   B  

... more follows
```

Groups of IDs 4 and 5 belong together if they follow each in time. Thus rows that I marked "A" belong together, the same is true with "B".
The two As and two Bs belong together, as they are consecutive in their date.
Now what I would like to get is a SELECT which returns 4 columns, i. e. the two rows A in one row, as well as rows B in one row.

So the output should look like this:

```
ID4 DATE4        ID5 DATE5           Comment (no column, just comment)  
---------------------------------    ------------------------------------
4   02-JAN-2013  5   05-JAN-2013     First set of 4 and 5  
4   08-JAN-2013  5   12-JAN-2013     Second set of 4 and 5  

...more follows
```

(Columns ID4 and ID5 are obsolete of course, just for demonstration purpose)

I hope I made myself understandable? Does anybody have an idea?

---

UPDATE:
Thank you for your ideas and SELECTS, I am sorry for being not clear enough in putting my question.
Only pairs of 4s and 5s should be considered, and only in ascending order of date. For the example above Alex Pool's and Florin Ghita's solutions are great, THANK YOU!!
The date of a 4er must be less than or equal to the date of the 5er. If there is a 4er or 5er which has no matching partner, it can be ignored.

But here is another sample with real data and a pitfall (the solutions fail here):  Walking through data in the order of time, there are 2 rows with 5 following consecutively.

```
4    16.03.2012 17:49:28  A
5    10.05.2012 09:38:56  A1     Either A1 is possible
5    12.06.2012 07:51:03  A2     or A2 whichever is easier to code
4    12.06.2012 08:47:52  B
5    02.08.2012 11:27:43  B
4    03.08.2012 13:24:54  C
5    03.08.2012 14:14:07  C
4    04.08.2012 15:00:00      should be ignored, as there is no following 5er
```

Wanted output:

```
4    16.03.2012 17:49:28    5    10.05.2012 09:38:56   (alternat.:  5  12.06.2012 07:51:03)
4    12.06.2012 08:47:52    5    02.08.2012 11:27:43  
4    03.08.2012 13:24:54    5    03.08.2012 14:14:07
```

The suggested SELECTS fail as they do not regard that a 4er must be prior to a 5er in time. If there is no corresponding partner, ignore this row. I had not made myself clear enough, sorry.

Thank you very much
Friedhelm

Comment: I don't quite understand if this is specific to IDs 4 & 5 or not? If for instance you had an ID 7 with a date of the 10-Jan-2013 would this be group C? If that's the case aren't you just looking for any ID in your table that appears more than once?

Comment: I don't get it. I fail to see why the "second" A is considered "consecutive" as there is a gap of two days between the two dates. And why does the row with January 7th not get an A as it is also "follows" the others in time?

Comment: Yes, it is specific to IDs 4 and 5 only. I added an update maybe this makes it clearer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other commenters I'm not entirely sure I follow, but if you only want to look at IDs 4 and 5 and want to match them up in date order, you can do something like this:

```sql
with t as (
    select id, dt, row_number() over (partition by id order by dt) as rn
    from t42
    where id in (4, 5)
)
select t4.id as id4, t4.dt as date4, t5.id as id5, t5.dt as date5,
    case t4.rn when 1 then 'First' when 2 then 'Second' when 3 then 'Third' end
        || ' set of 4 and 5' as "Comment"
from t t4
join t t5 on t5.rn = t4.rn
where t4.id = 4
and t5.id = 5
order by t4.rn;

       ID4 DATE4            ID5 DATE5     Comment             
---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------------------
         4 02-JAN-13          5 05-JAN-13 First set of 4 and 5  
         4 08-JAN-13          5 12-JAN-13 Second set of 4 and 5
```

I'm not sure now if you actually want the 'comment' to be returned/displayed... probably not, which would simplify it slightly.

---

For modified requirements:

```
with t as (
    select id, dt, lead(dt) over (partition by id order by dt) as next_dt
    from t42
    where id in (4, 5)
)
select t4.id as id4, t4.dt as date4, t5.id as id5, min(t5.dt) as date5
from t t4
join t t5 on t5.dt > t4.dt and (t4.next_dt is null or t5.dt <= t4.next_dt)
where t4.id = 4
and t5.id = 5
group by t4.id, t4.dt, t5.id
order by t4.dt;

       ID4 DATE4                        ID5 DATE5               
---------- --------------------- ---------- ---------------------
         4 16.03.2012 17:49:28            5 10.05.2012 09:38:56   
         4 12.06.2012 08:47:52            5 02.08.2012 11:27:43   
         4 03.08.2012 13:24:54            5 03.08.2012 14:14:07
```

The CTE uses `LEAD` to peek at the next date for each ID, which is only really relevant for when ID is 4; and that can be null if there isn't an extra ID 4 without matches at the end. The join then only looks for ID 5 records that fall between two ID 4 dates (or after the last ID 4 date). If you want the alternate (later) ID 5 date in the first result just use `MAX` instead of `MIN`. (I'm not 100% about the `>` and `<=` matching; I've tried to interpret what you said, but you might need to tweak that if it isn't quite right).

---

To work around what appears to be a 9i bug (probably fixed in 9.2.0.3 or 9.2.0.6 according to MOS, but depends exectly which bug you're hitting):

```
select t4.id as id4, t4.dt as date4, t5.id as id5, min(t5.dt) as date5
from (
    select id, dt, lead(dt) over (partition by id order by dt) as next_dt
    from t42
    where id = 4
) t4
join (select id, dt
    from t42
    where id = 5
) t5 on t5.dt > t4.dt and (t4.next_dt is null or t5.dt <= t4.next_dt)
group by t4.id, t4.dt, t5.id
order by t4.dt;
```

I don't have an old enough version to test this against unfortunately. You don't have to use the `t5` subselect, you could just join your main table straight to `t4`, but I think this is a little clearer.

Comment: @FlorinGhita - yes, that's why you beat me *8-) Having read it again I don't think it's needed!

Comment: lol, yes, but I also think intense on that `full outer join` :))

Comment: Indeed, comments were not needed ;-) Works very well with my first sample data, thank you! But I found another sample data which has a pitfall, see my edit above. Sorry my fault.

Comment: @user2065234 - I've added a variation that works for your second set of data, as well as the first. Hopefully you can tweak that to account for any additional requirements (or pitfalls).

Comment: Your posted result is exactly what I need - but my TOAD, SQL-Developer and SQLPlus say "ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kkqwrm_noref: COLFDNF set], [], [], [], [], [], [], []" when that statement is executed. Our database is Oracle Enterprise Edition 9.2.0.1.0. - and running fine.

Comment: @user2065234 - ORA-600 is often caused by a bug; in this case I can see a couple that might cause this, related to window functions in `WITH` clauses. Rewriting with subselects instead ought to work, if you can't patch up to at least 9.2.0.8, or something that's actually supported by Oracle *8-) I don't have an unpatched instance to test it against though.

Comment: @user2065234 - good, but... not sure why you accepted Chris' answer in that case. [You can also upvote other answers that were helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), incidentally, not just the one you accept as most useful.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is simple. Just rank your records based on ids.

```
with ranked_data

as (select 
       id, 
        date_col, 
       row_number() over (partition by id order by date_col) as rnk
   from your_table
   where id in (4, 5))

select t4.id as id4, t4.date_col as date4, t5.id as id5, t5.date_col as date5
from ranked_data t4
full outer join ranked_data t5 
  on (t4.rnk=t5.rnk and t4.id=4 and t5.id=5)
```

Comment: Snap. Why the full outer join though?

Comment: because there may be more fours than fives or viceversa?

Comment: I read it as the OP only being interested if they were paired as a set, but it's not clear what should happen if there are extras, so fair enough.

Comment: Works well, thank you! But I'm sorry I presented an example which was not representative enough. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible without a self join using analytics:

```
SELECT distinct 
         first_value(id) over (partition by rk order by dt), 
         min(dt) over (partition by rk),
         last_value(id) over (partition by rk order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) id5 ,
         max(dt) over (partition by rk) 
FROM (
SELECT id, dt, dense_rank() over (partition by id order by dt) rk 
FROM t
where  id in (4, 5)
)
```

This finds the value of id that corresponds to the "first" date, so if the order of the dates for 4 and 5 are reversed then you'll 5 will appear in the "4" column. It's not clear if this is what you want or not.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much for your solution. But I am sorry, your SELECT misses on my extended sample data which I added above. My fault that it did not include this. Sorry.

Comment: `row_number()` is analytical too, and that approach also only hits the base table once - it's the CTE that's self-joined. But this interesting.

Comment: @AlexPoole - true, but the table still appears twice in the explain plan if you do the CTE with a self join

Comment: It doesn't for me - I get a temp table transformation step and the two hits are against the temp table. As long as I include the filter inside the CTE. But this is a tiny dummy table with no key or index so probably don't want to overthink it or extrapolate to how it'll behave in the real world *8-) I'll bear this in mind anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole - interesting; I get a merge join accessing the table twice. Definitely agree on not overthinking/extrapolating this to the real world though!